# Recommendation MongoDB Schema Design for Big Schedule

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

I'm learning MongoDB, I need schema design recommendations.

So, I have prayer times for several cities. I made 1 document for 1 province out of 34 provinces.

This is an example of a province:

```js
{
  name: "Province A",
  slug: "province-a",
  cities: [
    {
      name: 'City A',
      slug: 'city-a',
      latitude: `4° 09' 31.76" N`,
      longtitude: `96° 07' 28.86" E`
      times: {
        "2021": {
          "1": {
            "1": {
              date: 'Friday, 01/01/2021',
              imsak: '05:11',
              subuh: '05:21',
              terbit: '06:39',
              dhuha: '07:08',
              dzuhur: '12:42',
              ashar: '16:05',
              maghrib: '18:39',
              isya: '19:53'
            },
            "2": {
              date: 'Saturday, 02/01/2021',
              imsak: '05:11',
              subuh: '05:21',
              terbit: '06:39',
              dhuha: '07:08',
              dzuhur: '12:42',
              ashar: '16:05',
              maghrib: '18:39',
              isya: '19:53'
            },
            // other date ...
          },
          // other month ...
        },
        // other year (2021 - 2030) ...
      }
    },
    // other city
  ]
}
```

**Is this good practice?**

**If not, can you provide an example of a best practice for data like mine?**

Thanks in advance, I really appreciate any answer.

Answer (score 0):

no, i don't think is a best pratice putting All the document inside raccomandations schema but only the _id of reccommended entity.

here an example of how save the data for recommendation (scrool at bottom of docs for the schema): https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-recommended-plugin